# How to override Cargo crate Dependencies of two different versions of crate using patch.crates-io?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I am trying to patch problematic crate that is included indirectly by crates that I  include in my project. But issue is, I see two different crates use two different versions of problematic crate. Using `patch.crates-io`, I could patch just one version of problematic crate.

To explain my problem, here is the code illustration.

Lets say I have a project called 'myproject' which includes Crate 'A' and Crate 'B'. Both Crate 'A' and Crate 'B' includes Crate 'C' but two different version (Lets say 0.1.1 and 0.2.2). But crate 'C' needs some customization to fix some issues that is affecting my project. After making local copies of both versions, I made some fixes and now I want to update myproject with patch.crates-io like below. But I could provide patch to only one version of Crate 'C'.

In myproject.toml

```ini
[patch.crates-io]
C = { version = "0.1.1", path = "../mylocalpath/C" }
```

So question is, is there a way of patching both versions of crate 'C' without making local copies of crate 'A' or crate 'B'?

Comment: Does this section of the reference answer your question: [Using patch with multiple versions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#using-patch-with-multiple-versions)?

Answer (score 3):

I found Rodrigo's comment very helpful.

If you want a code example, here i've done so with the crate `rand`:

```
[patch.crates-io]
rand = { version = "0.8.5", git = "https://github.com/rust-random/rand", rev="0.8.5" }
rand2 = { version = "0.7.3", git = "https://github.com/rust-random/rand", rev="0.7.3", package="rand" }
```

If you run cargo tree, you can see that the patch has been applied.